# Subsonic 2.0 Slow on High volume processing

Tags: performance, subsonic

I have a c# cmd line application that reads xml file in and updates the database using subsonic 2.0

Initial load of data was processing 400k records at a rate of 60k/hour

Over time the process is slowing up 1200/hour

When i do a sql restart the process speeds up but slows down again after a few days

the process runs nightly and the volume of records can vary.

Is there any issuess with the subsonic sql being cached everytime a request is made which is slowing sql 2010 up?

I have ran perfmon and all seems ok and I am  investigating for memory leak using dotTrace - but I still think its a sql issue

Comment: Is this doing Inserts? Do you have any Indexes defined?

Comment: if I run DBCC FREEPROCCACHE WITH NO_INFOMSGS; and DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS [ WITH NO_INFOMSGS ] on the database it seems to fix it. There is a very complex client fron end to the system with lots of stored procs that access the database that seem to be increaing the query plan cache - this has no noticiple affect to the user expectation - but the proceses need to run very fast